# sending iPhone UUID over SMS and Email

Tags: ios, security

I'm planning on sending a user's UUID to other users of my app using SMS or Email. I'm assuming that the user's UUID is a relatively sensitive piece of information, so it makes sense to encrypt it? If so, how should I go about doing this?

Getting the UUID with this code (I'm only planning on supporting iOS 6 and > )

```
NSString *UUID = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super sensitive, since it's not the device's actual UUID, but a randomly generated one that is unique to your app. It's no more sensitive than a UUID you created yourself.

What determines its "sensitivity" is how you're planning to use it. With that UUID, could I impersonate your end user somehow? Could I gain access to their data? Would that be problematic?

If the answer is "no", then go ahead and send it unencrypted. If it's "yes", then encrypt it. There's plenty of built-in encryption methods in the Security framework.